# Change Order of Database Backups

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren

Can I specify a specific database to be backed up first and another database after that?

For example in the following order:

1. DB2
2. DB3
3. DB1

The code which I am currently using is as follows:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] 
    @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', 
    @Directory = N'E:\MSSQL\Backup', 
    @BackupType = 'FULL', 
    @Verify = 'Y',
    @CleanupTime = 180, 
    @Compress='Y', 
    @Encrypt = 'Y', 
    @EncryptionAlgorithm = 'AES_256', 
    @ServerCertificate = 'DBCertificate',
    @CheckSum = 'Y',
    @CleanupMode = 'BEFORE_BACKUP',  
    @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

Comment: Well for starters, you can't reorder the backup of `master` and `model`, because they are both system databases and your query is set to run on `USER_DATABASES`. It might help if you clarify that bit first. (`USER_DATABASES` vs. `SYSTEM_DATABASES`)

Comment: @hot2use I have amended my question to DB3,DB3,DB1 rather than master and model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been released in the latest version as below:

https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/47

You'll need to add the list of database names to the @Databases parameter - but do check through the documentation and Github site for clarification.

As hot2use states above, master and model will never be covered by this script though, as they are not user databases.

I would suggest you give the documentation a read [here](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html).

Comment: I have used master and model just as an example.

Comment: @syedRehaan feel free to mark this as the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @george.Palcious I have just tried this now                      
        databases = ' 
  DBNAME3,DBNAME1,DBNAME5,DBNAME2,DBNAME4,USER_DATABASES'  but this didn't work for me. Is there anything else I need to change please?

Comment: This should work. Could you download the latest version and try again.
https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html

If it still does not work, please post your backup command again, with all the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @OlaHallengren . I will test this again and keep you posted here.Thanks for your response.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a ton @OlaHallengren